# One Nginx Rewrite Rule Needed

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm stuck with one broken nginx rewrite rule on my site, and this is my last glimmer of hope in getting it fixed.

The apache rule is this:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+) image.php?id=$1&width=$2&height=$3&cropratio=$4 [L]
```

I've made it this far, but it's still not working

```
rewrite ^/file/([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^/.]+) /image.php?id=$1&width=$2&height=$3&cropratio=$4 last;
```

or even this:

```
rewrite ^/file/([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+) /image.php?id=$1&width=$2&height=$3&cropratio=$4 last;
```

None of my images are showing up, so if anyone has a solution that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
location /file/ {
    rewrite ^/file/([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+) /image.php?id=$1&width=$2&height=$3&cropratio=$4 break;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I've tried few similar variations before without any success. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Could you please five me a sample link and a location it should go to? I want to try this on my server.